# Density density correlations of a simple Brownian particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density, correlation-functions, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

Suppose, I have a particle satisfying the equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{dX}{dt}=\eta(t)
\end{equation}
Where $\langle \eta(t)\eta(t')\rangle=\delta(t-t')$. I can now define a density like $\rho(x,t)=\delta(x-X(t))$. I am confused how do I compute $$\langle \rho(x,t)\rho(x',t')\rangle~?$$ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Physics StackExchange! This question can be related to the calculation of dynamic density correlations in liquids, in the diffusion limit. Because of this, and the familiarity of the results in that physical application, I'm going to explicitly include the diffusion coefficient $D$ in the right-hand side of the Brownian dynamics equation (Langevin equation without inertia) and write
$$
\langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle = 2D\,\delta(t-t')
$$
but obviously the result for your equation will follow from setting 
$D=\frac{1}{2}$.
It is also standard to assume that $\langle \eta(t)\rangle=0$ and
that 
$\eta(t)$ is a *Gaussian* random process, so all its higher moments are
determined by the first two: you don't explicitly state this, 
but I assume that it is true.

Direct integration of the equation gives the usual results $\langle \Delta X\rangle = 0$ and $\langle \Delta X^2\rangle = 2D |t-t'|$,
where $\Delta X=X(t)-X(t')$.

Your interest lies in the density-density correlation function
$$
G(x,t,x',t') = G(x-x',t-t') = \left\langle \rho(x,t) \, \rho(x',t') \right\rangle
$$
where $\rho(x,t)=\delta(x-X(t))$.
I've incorporated here the fact that the system is translationally invariant
in both the space and time coordinates.
This in turn means that the time correlation function
of the Fourier transformed density 
$$\tilde{\rho}(k,t)=
\int \rho(x,t) \exp(-ikx) dx
=\exp [-ikX(t)]$$
which we write
$$
F(k,t-t') = \left\langle \tilde{\rho}(k,t) \tilde{\rho}(-k,t') \right\rangle
$$
is itself the Fourier transform of $G$:
$$
F(k,t) = \int G(x,t) \exp(-ikx) dx
$$
More details on these kind of manipulations may be found, for example,
in *Theory of Simple Liquids* by J-P Hansen and IR McDonald.
In our case, from the definition of $\tilde{\rho}(k,t)$,
$$
F(k,t-t') = \left\langle \exp [-ik\{X(t)-X(t')\}] \right\rangle
= \left\langle \exp [-ik \Delta X] \right\rangle
$$
Now we use the Gaussian nature of the random term $\eta$,
which implies that $\Delta X$ is also distributed as a Gaussian,
and satisfies the identity
$$
\left\langle \exp [-ik \Delta X] \right\rangle = 
\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}k^2 \langle \Delta X^2\rangle \right)
=
\exp \left(-Dk^2 |t-t'| \right)
$$
This is a familiar diffusional form,
a Gaussian function of $k$,
and we can immediately deduce the form of $G$,
which is a Gaussian in $x$:
$$
G(x-x',t-t') = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D\,|t-t'|}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x')^2}{4D\,|t-t'|}\right)
$$
You may need to check in case I have made any slips along the way.

This problem may also be approached by interpreting the density-density correlation function in the sense of a conditional probability
which satisfies the partial differential equation corresponding to the
original Langevin-like equation. That PDE is, of course, the diffusion equation,
and $G$ is the solution of it which you get when you set up the initial probability distribution as a delta-function, in other words, it is the propagator. But I've deliberately approached this as a problem involving dynamical variables based on $X(t)$, because that seemed to match the way the question is phrased.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you think about solving this problem using Dean's approach (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/29/24/001/meta).  Using his approach, we can write down the stochastic equation followed by $\rho(x,t)$.

Comment: Using ito calculus, we can show $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=-\nabla\cdot(\rho \eta)+\nabla^2\rho$. I was trying to find the density density correlation by solving this stochastic differential equation but couldn't wrap my head around it. Do you have any idea how to proceed from here. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm unfamiliar with that paper, so I can't say much. Obviously, I would have expected to get the standard Fokker-Planck equation, which is what you have written down *without* the term involving $\eta$ (and hence is much easier!). See e.g. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) where it says "The zero-drift equation with constant diffusion ...". This is what I was referring to in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the term $-\frac{d}{dx} (\rho\eta)$ doesn't vanish? And is it really $\eta$, rather than $\langle \eta\rangle$? The random force is defined to have zero drift in your case, isn't it?

Comment: Using the Fokker-Planck formalism, it is easy. I wanted to solve it via this method as I was trying to solve some other problem. I wanted to see if I can get the correlations via dean's approach.

Comment: I don't think it vanishes. I think there is a subtle difference in fokker-planck and deans method. I am not sure though.

Comment: I think we've reached the limit of my expertise here. My gut feeling is that the raw stochastic process $\eta(t)$ shouldn't be appearing in the Fokker-Planck-like equation, and that some averaging over $\eta(t)$ should have taken place. It looks like the problem you really want to solve is more complicated than the original question! Good luck.

Comment: What I can think is, that from the fokker planck equation you cannot solve the correlations in density. It is a deterministic equation of the density.

Comment: But my answer shows how it is done! The solution $G(x,t)$ is really $\rho(x,t)$ but *conditional on* the original density being a delta function at the origin. So it is *both* a solution of the diffusion equation *and* equivalent to $\langle \rho(x,t)\,\rho(0,0) \rangle$, which is a correlation function. Have a look at the appropriate chapters on dynamics, correlation functions, and linear response theory in Hansen and McDonald, or possibly a statistical mechanics text such as DA McQuarrie, or Mark Tuckerman's book *Statistical Mechanics, Theory and Simulation*. These may help.