# Density Fluctuation in N-Particle Brownian Motions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

I am studying spatial population movement and would like to model the density fluctuation by assuming a Brownian movement for each individual. Because the total number of individual ($N$) is large but finite, there must be some statistical fluctuations of density distribution in a bounded region $V$.

Let us define $\rho(x,t)$ as the local density at spatial location $x\in V$ at time $t$. Now assume that the population has not reached equilibrium, so they should follow the standard diffusion equation with a **stochastic** noise term:

$$
\partial_t\rho=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}\rho+\eta(x,t)
$$

Let us only focus on the one-dimensional case. Suppose we discretize space into small intervals of length $\Delta x$, and at $t_0$ the density distribution is $\rho_{t_0}(x)$. Let us further define the probability density function for the spatial location of these $N$ particles, as $p_t(x)$. Obviously,
$p_t(x)=\rho_{t}(x)/N$. Also, the $i$-th particle's spatial location at time $t$ is denoted as $X_i^{(t)}$.

Now time has evolved from $t_0$ to $t_1$. Since each particle is doing Brownian motion, the probability for the $i$-th particle to fall into the small interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$ is:

$$
\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t_1)}\le x+\Delta x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_{t_0}(s)\mathbb{P}(x\le s+W_{t_2-t_1}\le x+\Delta x)\text{d}s\quad(1\le i\le N),
$$
where $W_t$ is the standard brownian motion.

Let $C_{t_{1}}(x)^{(\Delta x)}$ be the number of particles at time $t_1$ in the small interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$. It is a random variable following a Binomial distribution with $N$ trials and probability $\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t)}\le x+\Delta x)$, so its variance is

$$
\text{Var}[C_{t_{1}}(x)^{(\Delta x)}]=N\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t)}\le x+\Delta x)(1-\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t)}\le x+\Delta x))
$$

We want to see the limit of the variance of $\rho(x,t_1)$ (both $x$ and $t_1$ are **fixed**, so it is essentially a random variable) when $\Delta x\to 0$. We can take the limit

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}[\rho(x,t_1)]&=\text{Var}\left[\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\cfrac{C_{t_{1}}(x)^{(\Delta x)}}{\Delta x}\right]\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{N}{(\Delta x)^2}\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t)}\le x+\Delta x)(1-\mathbb{P}(x\le X_i^{(t)}\le x+\Delta x))\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{N^2}{N\Delta x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_{t_0}(s)\frac{\mathbb{P}(x\le s+W_{t_2-t_1}\le x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\text{d}s\\
\end{align*}
$$
where I have dropped the $(1-\mathbb{P}(\cdots))$ term because it approaches $1$. Also, let $N\Delta x=K$, so $N$ will scale up when $\Delta x$ goes down. And notice that the limit of the integral is simply the initial probability distribution convoluted with a Gaussian kernal, which gives the expected probability distribution $\bar{p}_{t_1}(x)$ at time $t_1$. So we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}[\rho(x,t_1)]&=\frac{N^2}{K}\bar{p}_{t_1}(x)\\
&=\frac{N}{K}\mathbb{E}[\rho(x,t_1)]
\end{align*}
$$

This means the variance of density at a particular spatial location and at a particular time is the expectation of that density scaled by the particle number $N$ (and the constant $K$).

It is what I have got so far. The ultimate goal is to derive the noise term $\eta(x,t)$ that would produce the exact same randomness in the distribution. The problem is that since the total number of particle is fixed, the noise cannot be spatially independent. There must be some spatial correlation to cancel out the overall noise effect to keep the total number of particles unchanged. I am a biologist with some mathematics background but am relatively unfamiliar with physics literatures. And I suspect that there should be some statistical mechanics models which have already explored this topic. Any help with this issue is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean when you say you've tried to "find out the noise term"? Are you trying to extract the noise term by fitting to data? Are you looking for a particular model of the noise term? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @probably_someone I tried to derive the noise term from N-particle brownian motion. e.g. looking for a particular model of the noise term where the noise only reflects the dispersal stochasticity from the finite number of particles.

Comment: Just to make sure that I'm understanding your problem correctly: the noise term $\eta(x,t)$ is a random variable whose distribution is a function of space and time, correct? If that's true, why can't $\eta(x,t)$ be a Poisson-distributed random variable with expectation value $\rho(x,t)V$ for pixel volume $V$?

Comment: @probably_someone Thank you. Yes, $\eta(x,t)$ is a random variable across space and time. I did some calculation and arrived at a Poisson distribution of particle numbers for a single pixel volume $V$. But the overall noise term, when integrated across space, should be zero due to mass conservation. And ultimately we need to let $V\to 0$, so scaling $N$ according to $V$ correctly would be crucial, I'll update the question later today. Thank you

Comment: The question has been updated with more details

Comment: I think this is similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/424698/density-density-correlations-of-a-simple-brownian-particle (see the refrence given by the poster: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/29/24/001/meta)

Comment: How large is $N$? I would assume that the natural thing is to study the equation of motion of $N$ particles, subject to brownian motion. If they are non-interacting, this reduces to the motion of one particle only. On the other hand, if they are interacting, it is not clear to me why they should follow a diffusion equation at all.

Comment: @LorenzMayer. They are not interacting. I don't think they could be simplified to one particle only, because the more particles there are , the closer the realized density distribution is to the theoretical expectation. While a single particle will never generate an empirical distribution that looks like the expected one.

Comment: @LorenzMayer  someone from the math stackexchange suggests me this inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality

Comment: Have you taken a look how diffusion equations arise in the thermodynamic limit out of Langevin equations for single-particle dynamics? As always, the fluctuations will scale as $N^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, where $N$ is the number of particles, which looks like what you are looking for. In any case i would assume that starting from the Langevin equations is a better starting point, from a fundamental point of view, then starting from the diffusion equation and adding a noise term.